# how to response the scroll event of outer parent page in a iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, scroll

I have a app in Taobao.com, when the app loads, Taobao.com loads the html content from my callback url, and constructs a iframe in final page. Now I want a div in my html to move up and down with the scroll of the outer page (in Taobao.com, this div is positioned in a iframe). How to response the scroll event of outer parent page in a iframe? Is there any other solutions to implement my effect?

I've tried

```
$(parent).scroll(function(){})
```

and

```
$(parent.document).scroll(function(){})
```

both not working.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your app in question ?

Comment: @Didier Ghys, http://yingyong.taobao.com/show.htm?app_id=125002, but Taobao account is required.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
$(window.parent.document).scroll(function() {});
```

**update**

here's an example on jsfiddle with the `mousemove` event: http://fiddle.jshell.net/DuBPL/1/ (no scroll because of the interface of jsfiddle, but you'll see it does work)

Note that this won't (ever) work if you have an iFrame with for example the src domain1.com and the parent on domain2.com.

Comment: sorry,not working, I debugged in chrome, $(window.parent.document) => []

Comment: I konw, my iframe src is loading from domain1.com, and the parent page is on Taobao.com, maybe this is the reason for not working.

Comment: is there any other solutions to implement this?